# JPA best way to avoid n+1 when I need to make a calculation for each row

Tags: performance, loops, jpa

My application is used to find place in a city. Each place needs a score to be calculated and this score cannot be predicted in advance (stored somewhere) as it is different for each user and changes over time. Here is was i'm at the moment doing an that is TERRIBLY inneficient (15 times slower than if I mock the database call inside the loop)

1. SQL(native) query to fetch all the places that matches the search (I select all the column I need specifically)
2. I loop through the List and for each poi I make a db call to get the info needed to calculate the scores (I need different value residing on different tables)
3. make the calculation
4. sort by score desc
5. cut the list depending on the pagination setting (yes I cannot put LIMIT directly in the query as i don't know the score yet....)
6. return the List.

Well, this takes 15 seconds in total. 
If I remove 2. and simply mock the DB call it only takes 600ms..

my table looks like this:

```
place_tag_count table:
place_id / tag_id / tag_count
1           100      15
1           200      25
1           300      35

user_tag_score Table:
user_id / tag_id / score
1000        100      0.5
1000        200      0.3
```

as a simplified example the place score is the sum of the user's tag score multiplied by the tag count found in the place_tag_count

```
score = 0.5 * 15 + 0.3 * 25 + (i won't complicate the thing but if a tag score is missing i do other calculation that need other db calls....)
```

the query at 1. returns a distinct place so because the calculation needs all the counts from of the tag's place and the user's tag score I need to make that extra DB call for each poi.

My question is, what would be the BEST way to avoid having n+1 call in my situation? I have thought to some alternative but I prefer having the opinion of a more experience person before going head first.

1. Instead of returning a distinct place in the query in 1) I actually return the same place grouped by place_id,tag_id for example, and in my Java code I just loop and when I see that the place_id change it means I'm processing an other place
2. make the query in 1. a bitttt more complicate and aggregate all the numbers i need in a comma separated list )but that requires some kind of sub select which might affect the speed of the query)
3. other solution ?

Comment: By the way I'm using a native query because I need to make joj on different predicate (left on .. AND ..) and JPQL doesn't support this...

Comment: JPQL supports "ON" in JOINs

Comment: Only with EclipseLink no? (I'm using hibernate, I know hibernate has the "with" keyword but hibernate doesn't support HAVING count(*) which my query uses.)

Comment: JPQL has "ON" with JPA 2.1, and *any JPA2.1 implementation* should support it (DataNucleus JPA certainly does, what i use)

Comment: indeed, I just tried. and it works, well that's good news thanks !